# Session variable not being unset

Tags: php

I have a website that takes a username and passwd.  When entered correctly a username session variable is created.  However, when I go into another page and check to see if the variable is set I get false.

Here is my code to set the variable.

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

```
if ($username == "right username" || $password == "rigthpassword"){

    session_start();

    $_SESSION["username"] = "aadsj2als378909382lkklja";
    $_SESSION["password"] = "ajklsd89798798jlk09779023";

}
```

I then have a php script that checks if a user is logged in.  If the user is logged in then it goes to one page if not it goes to another page.  However, it going to the page that it should go to if the user is not logged in however the user is logged in.

```
<?php session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){

        header('Location:http://website.com/page1.php');

    } else {

        header('Location:http://website.com/page2.php');

    }

?>
```

So after I login I click on the link that runs this script however.   Instead of taking me to page 2 it takes me to page 1.  Which it shouldn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI `$username == "right username" || $password == "rigthpassword"`. i think you want a `&&` not `||`

Comment: thanks for that.  But that isn't causing the problem.

Comment: Looks like your 2 pages are on different domains. `website.com` and `webpage.com`. Is that just a typo? or are they really on different domains.

Comment: Do you get any warnings?  If you have sent any output before the `session_start` you might have problems.  You could add a `ob_start` in the beginning of the page in case you have that issue.  Let me know if that's the issue, and if it worked.

Comment: no warnings.  I added ob_start but still having the same issue.

Comment: the weird part is after I login and redirect to the correct page.  I have the commands for a user that is logged in but when I go to another link that performs the same check it doesn't work.

Comment: Check what value `session_id()` has in both pages after you do the session_start(), and/or do a `var_dump($_SESSION)`. If you get different ids, then you've got different sessions.

Comment: you should change to `header("Location: page1.php");` or `header("Location: page2.php");`! Should be safer than supplying a domain, even if it is the same.

Comment: Marc B was right the session id is different when I move between pages.  I don't understand why.  Isn't session_start() suppose to continue to previous session?

Answer (score 0):

1. session_start(); function use top of the page   (no line break after php one tage )

2 if ($username == "rightusername" && $password == "rigthpassword"){

```
$_SESSION["username"] = "aadsj2als378909382lkklja";
$_SESSION["password"] = "ajklsd89798798jlk09779023";
```

}

change the code like this, test the $username,$password  content ..

Comment: Adding a a line break will not change anything `<?php session-start()` is perfectly acceptable PHP code.

Comment: What comes back when you `print_r($_SESSION)` after these variables are already set?  Are you spelling it right?

Comment: just a quick stupid question.  The session_start() am I suppose to do that at the start of every page that is going to check if a variable is set or just when I set the variable?

Comment: @user541597 yes, you need to add session_start() to the beginning of all the pages where $_SESSION is used.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this might be a bit obvious, but with this...

```
if ($username == "right username" || $password == "rigthpassword"){

    session_start();

    $_SESSION["username"] = "aadsj2als378909382lkklja";
    $_SESSION["password"] = "ajklsd89798798jlk09779023";

}
```

How are you retrieving those values? I'm assuming you're using the post method. Meaning it should be something more to the nature of...

```
    if ($_POST['username'] == "right username" || $_POST['password'] == "rigthpassword"){
session_start();

        $_SESSION["username"] = "aadsj2als378909382lkklja";
        $_SESSION["password"] = "ajklsd89798798jlk09779023";
    }
```

My guess is that you must be improperly sending the variables. Can you post the code for your login form?

login.html

```
<form method="POST" action="http://mysite.com/login.php">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_POST['username'] == "password" && $_POST['password'] == "password") {
$_SESSION['username'] == "aadsj2als378909382lkklja";
$_SESSION['password'] == "ajklsd89798798jlk09779023";
}
?>
```

otherpage.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("location: http://website.com/page1.php");
} else {
header("location: http://website.com/page1.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Well based on your code it should be working just fine. So my only assumption is that somehow the variables aren't being sent correctly. If this isn't the case then I think there is something you're not posting which is causing the issues.

Comment: I've found that different sessions are being created when I do session_start() instead of continuing the last session.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, the login code which creates the session is on another page right? You're not calling it multiple times and generating new code each time?

Comment: on root directory I have a folder called admin inside I have index.php.  This page contains the login prompt.  This info is posted to another php page. which does a session_start then checks for the correct user info and sets the username and password session variables.  From there it loads the index.php page on the root directory.  Which again does session_start() then later in the code checks to see if username session variable is set.  This works fine.  However from this index page when I go to another page on the root directory using session-start() I don't get the variable as being set.

Comment: I made an edit with working code, if you want to send me the files at the email I provided above I'll see if I can get it working for you. (remove sensitive information of course)

Comment: one more thing.  After I redirect after login.  I get the admin controls.  However when I go to another webpage that should have the controls I don't.  However, from that page that doesn't have controls if I go to another page then I do have controls on the next page.

Comment: That's really odd man, however I can't help you without seeing all your code. So my offer stands if you want to send me some of your files I'll look into it and see if there are any updates I can make to fix your issues.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10244/discussion-between-user541597-and-ian)